# Function works on Mozilla but not Eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cordova

I have a form and function that works perfectly when opened with Mozilla Firefox but fails to run on eclipse. It is a PhoneGap application calculating BMI. The error states that the function calculate is undefined.

It's my first time posting here and I'm only doing this after spending hours trying to fix it myself. This is the code that I use:

```js
function calculate(height, weight, gender, age, dweight, efreq) {
  var realbmi = (weight / (height * height));

  //if else variables
  var classification, bmr, advice, daysleft;

  if (realbmi < 18.5) {
    classification = "Underweight";
  } else if ((18.5 <= realbmi) && (realbmi <= 24.99)) {
    classification = "Normal Weight";
  } else if ((25 <= realbmi) && (realbmi <= 29.99)) {
    classification = "Overweight";
  } else if ((30 <= realbmi) && (realbmi <= 34.99)) {
    classification = "Obese (class 1)";
  } else if ((35 <= realbmi) && (realbmi <= 39.99)) {
    classification = "Obese (class 2)";
  } else {
    classfication = "Morbidly Obese";
  }

  if (gender == "male") {
    bmr = (66 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.8 * age));
  } else {
    bmr = (655 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age));
  }

  var maintenance = efreq * bmr;

  if (dweight < weight) {
    advice = "You need to lose" + " " + (weight - dweight) + "kg";
  } else if (weight < dweight) {
    advice = "You need to gain" + " " + (dweight - weight) + "kg";
  } else {
    advice = "Try to maintain weight";
  }

  if (dweight < weight) {
    daysleft = "Days to target weight (at 500 cal. less per day):" + ((weight - dweight) / 0.064);
  } else if (dweight > weight) {
    daysleft = "Days to target weight (at 500 cal. more per day):" + ((dweight - weight) / 0.064);
  } else {
    daysleft = "";
  }

  localStorage.setItem("realbmi", realbmi);
  localStorage.setItem("classification", classification);
  localStorage.setItem("bmr", bmr);
  localStorage.setItem("maintenance", maintenance);
  localStorage.setItem("advice", advice);
  localStorage.setItem("daysleft", daysleft);
  localStorage.setItem("weight", parseFloat(document.bmiform.weight.value));
  localStorage.setItem("height", parseFloat(document.bmiform.height.value));
  localStorage.setItem("age", parseFloat(document.bmiform.age.value));
  localStorage.setItem("dweight", parseFloat(document.bmiform.dweight.value));

  document.bmiform.submit();

}
```

```html
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <p>Enter your height and weight. The system will calculate your BMI.</p>
  <div class="üi-field-contain">
    <form name="bmiform" id="bmiform" action="bmiresult.html">
      <label for="height">Height</label>
      <input type="text" name="height" id="height" placeholder="enter height in meters">

      <label for="weight">Weight</label>
      <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" placeholder="enter weight in KG">

      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Gender</legend>
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" checked>
        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
      </fieldset>

      <label for="dweight">Dream Weight</label>
      <input type="text" name="dweight" id="dweight" placeholder="enter dream weight in KG">

      <label for="age">Age</label>
      <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="enter age">

      <label for="efreq">Exercise Frequency</label>
      <select name="efreq" id="efreq">
        <option value="1.2">Hardly Exercise</option>
        <option value="1.375">Exercise 1 to 3 times per week</option>
        <option value="1.55">Exercise 3 to 5 times per week</option>
        <option value="1.725">Exercise 6 to 7 times per week</option>
        <option value="1.9">Exercise intensively more than 7 times per week</option>
      </select>

      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate(parseFloat(document.bmiform.height.value),parseFloat(document.bmiform.weight.value),
                document.bmiform.gender.value, parseFloat(document.bmiform.age.value), parseFloat(document.bmiform.dweight.value),
                document.bmiform.efreq.value);">

    </form>
```

Comment: Where is the `<script>` in the HTML? Also, are you sure that one `<div>`’s `class` should be `üi-field-contain` instead of `ui-field-contain`? Anyway, if it works in Firefox, there’s no real issue. It works where it’s supposed to work.

Comment: Why do you want this to be running in Eclipse at all?

Comment: Because it's a school project and I have to demonstrate it using an Android emulator

Comment: The script is in the <head> tags on the html page while the form is in the body.

Comment: How about using `addEventListener` instead of an inline handler?